# Workaround for DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: c#, linq, enums, entity-framework-core

I have something like this:

```
public enum CoolEnum
{
  Yes = 0,
  No = 1,
  Perhaps = 2,
  Maybe = 3,
  Perchance = 4,
}
```

and I want to do the following:

```
CoolEnum? enum = await this.context
                .MyTable
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .Select(x => x.CoolEnum)
                .DefaultIfEmpty((CoolEnum?)null)
                .FirstAsync();
```

but I get the error

```
Processing of the LINQ expression 'DefaultIfEmpty<Nullable<CoolEnum>> (...) failed.
This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.
```

As I have seen [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17783), it seems it's a known low priority issue.

Then I thought I could do the following:

```
CoolEnum enum = await this.context
                .MyTable
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .Select(x => x.CoolEnum)
                .FirstAsync();

CoolEnum? nullableEnum = enum == default ? null : enum;
```

But this will change all my existing enums with the default value to null, and that's not what I want.

Which clean workaround can I use? I see the following options:

- Return the whole object of MyTable. But if it's big, this is a waste of resources.
- Define a "null" default element in my Enum.
- Split the query in 2 queries, one to see if there are elements and the other to get the element.

Neither of them seems clean. Any better idea?

Comment: DefaultEmpty is used with a left outer join.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Comment: DefaultEmpty can be used in any other cotext as well,I think. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the nullable value (by using the regular C# cast to the corresponding nullable type) and then `FirstOrDefault{Async}`:

```
.Select(x => (CoolEnum?)x.CoolEnum)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```